# how to capture httpresponse in custom field

Tags: apex

I have written this code. I want to store response in response sms history field of sms history obj.here is code.

```
String body= '[{"from_number":"+14145337913","messages": [{"text":  "'+message+'","to_number": "'+phonenumber+'"}]}]';
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' +  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
             req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
             req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
             HTTPResponse res= new HTTPResponse();
             req.setBody(body); 
             system.debug(req.getBody());
             Http http = new Http();
             res = http.send(req);
             **response=res;**
        SMS_History__c SMSHistory = new SMS_History__c();
        if(res.getstatuscode()==200)
        {
                //system.debug('Authentication success@@@@@@@'+ res);
                SMSHistory.Name = SMSHistory.Name+' Succeeded';
                SMSHistory.Status__c = 'SMS Sent Successfully';

        }
```

but it showing error `"Illegal assignment from System.HttpResponse to String"`
when I used

```
string response=res;
```

Any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to do this like

```
SMSHistory.response__c = res.getBody();
SMSHistory.Name = SMSHistory.Name+' Succeeded';
SMSHistory.Status__c = 'SMS Sent Successfully';
```

or

```
string response=res.getBody();
```

Where `response__c` is the custom field API name(which you can change).